# How to print using qwebview using qt

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview, qwebkit

When accessing the link from a browser, there is a print button and when you click it the function print will show. And I cannot do this on my program having a qwebview. Im using qt4.7.3 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QWebView` has a `void print(QPrinter * printer) const` method. To show the print dialog, you'd use the `QPrintDialog` class.

You need to connect a `QAction` or some other signal to a slot that shows the print dialog, and another slot to the dialog's `accepted` signal.

```cpp
class MyWindow : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    QWebView * m_webView;
    QScopedPointer<QPrinter> m_printer;
    ...
    Q_SLOT void showPrintDialog() {
        if (!m_printer) m_printer.reset(new QPrinter);
        QScopedPointer<QPrintDialog> dialog(new QPrintDialog(m_printer.data(), this));
        dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
        connect(dialog.data(), SIGNAL(accepted(QPrinter*)), SLOT(print(QPrinter*)));
        dialog->show();
        dialog.take(); // The dialog will self-delete
    }
    Q_SLOT void print(QPrinter* printer) {
        m_webView->print(printer);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [the answer from Kuba Ober](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21262487/707700) and used it in my project as follows:

The `.ui` file contains a QWebView named 'webView', you can simply create this in QtCreator's *Design mode* .

Content of `.h` file

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QPrintDialog>

namespace Ui {
class myclassname;
}

class myclassname : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit myclassname(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~myclassname();

private slots:
    void print(QPrinter* printer);

    void on_pushButton_print_clicked();

private:
    Ui::myclassname *ui;
    QScopedPointer<QPrinter> m_printer;
};
```

Content of `.cpp` file

```
#include "myclassname.h"
#include "ui_myclassname.h"

myclassname::myclassname(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::myclassname)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->webView->load(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260463/how-to-print-using-qwebview-using-qt"));
}

myclassname::~myclassname()
{
    delete ui;
}

void myclassname::print(QPrinter* printer)
{
    ui->webView->print(printer);
}

void myclassname::on_pushButton_print_clicked()
{
    if (!m_printer) m_printer.reset(new QPrinter);
    QScopedPointer<QPrintDialog> dialog(new QPrintDialog(m_printer.data(), this));
    dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    connect(dialog.data(), SIGNAL(accepted(QPrinter*)), SLOT(print(QPrinter*)));
    dialog->show();
    dialog.take(); // The dialog will self-delete
}
```

Thank you @KubaOber

Comment: I noticed that the background of my QWebView stayed 'grey', and this uses unnecessary ink. I solved by adding `ui->webView->setStyleSheet("background-color: white");` to the constructor, just before the line `ui->webView->load(QUrl...`